# I understood the meaning of the situation.. But what this expression mean exactly?

Tags: meaning

"A bouncer pushed three women over during a shocking pub brawl. But was their use of force justified? "

The meaning of 
             over during a shocking pub brawl

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. I am not sure what exactly you are having difficulty with. You might wish to consider asking the question at English Language Learners on Stack Exchange. The doorman pushed the women over (pushed them to the ground) during a time when shoving or fighting was occurring at a public house.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the most common interpretation (and it's an English idiom) is:

**pushed three women over** -> **pushed three women to the floor**

Comment: Yes, as opposed to 'pushed them out of the door', 'pushed them into the street' and so on which imply that they might have staggered but did not fall down. There are other forms like 'pushed them down the steps' which don't specify that they fell but imply even more danger of injury.

Answer (score 0):

pushed **over**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/over)

> from an upright position

As in:

> physicality was used to impart motion to the women